# Access Token regular expression is getting passed correctly for 20% of the api calls

Tags: jmeter

I have 100 users login slowly in 30 mins and then 100 users concurrently for next 30 mins.
I see an error rate of 26%. And all of them failed because the access token value was not passed Instead I see the parameter name. Why would the access token not get passed ?. It's defined as regular expression.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say it's defined as a regular expression. In any case, I think we'll have to see the client code to know why this is happening. If I had to guess, I'd say some clients are running some bad or unsupported string interpolation code.

Comment: See the response of requests that return the token, they might have failed or returned an error

Answer (score 0):

It sends parameter name because:

- the extraction has failed
- you didn't provide the default value

The question why the extraction has failed is not something we can help with, most probably your application gets overloaded and instead of responding with the token responds with something else, you can add i.e. [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) listener (at least for the sampler which returns the token) or amend JMeter [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) to save the response data , this way you will be able to figure out what's wrong. See [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter) article for more detailed instructions if needed

It also makes sense to check the system under test logs.